# Running for multiple iterations and replications in Anylogic from an imported database

Tags: parameters, anylogic

I have imported a database table having data of 20 days [part of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onpAx.png) schedule and I want to run replications for each day's schedule to be in 95% CI. I have created a ParameterVariations experiment [multiplereps exp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpO1R.png) and tried to store output after each iteration while taking data from the database so that each day (of 20 days) replications run statistics can be exported separately, but it shows the error [after each iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBn3h.png). It will be helpful if there is some other easy way to do this. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. A simple "I don't know how" is not good enough here, you can use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.squarespace.com/blog/2021/11/12/an-introduction-to-the-anylogic-community. Welcome again, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `root` refers to the `Main` agent of your individual model runs.

You can only use this in the "After simulation run" code box, NOT in the "after iteration" code box (this is causing the error).

What you need to do is to store individual run results in the "After simulation run" code box using `root` into the experiment itself (i.e. put DataSet or other elements into the experiment screen).

Then in the "after iteration" code box, you can do any final post-processing by accessing the elements from the experiment screen.

PS: Check [this article on the magic lightbulb](https://benjamin-schumann.squarespace.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling) to understand which keywords to use when and where.